# processing the words common in the given input file and my query file

Tags: java, file, hash, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

There is a given input file for my homework. And I've created a query file which includes some of the words in the input file. I want to process the ones common. I also wrote different words in my query which is not included in input file.

```
package hw5;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input"));
    BufferedReader q = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("query"));

    BST<String, Integer> st = new BST<String, Integer>();
    BST<String, Integer> stq = new BST<String, Integer>();

    RedBlack<String, Integer> rb = new RedBlack<String, Integer>();

    SeparateChainingHashST<String, Integer> hash = new SeparateChainingHashST<String, Integer>();

    String line = null;
    String lineq = null;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      while ((lineq = q.readLine()) != null) {

        // System.out.println(line);
        long start1, start2, start3;
        long time, time2, time3;

        start1 = System.nanoTime();

        /*
         * for (int i = 0;i<lineq.length(); i++) {
         * if(stq.get(lineq).equals(st.get(line))) {
         */

        Integer val = 1;
        st.put(line, val);
        stq.put(lineq, val);
        // if(stq.get(lineq).equals(st.get(line))) {
        System.out.println(stq.get(line));
        // }
        // }

        time = (System.nanoTime() - start1)/1000;   // divided by 
                1000 because 1 nanosecond is 0.001 microsecond

      //    System.out.println("elapsed time " + time);

        start2 = System.nanoTime();

        rb.put(line, null);
        System.out.println(rb.get(line));

        time2 = (System.nanoTime() - start2)/1000;

        //System.out.println("elapsed time " + time2);

        start3 = System.nanoTime();

        hash.put(line, val);
        System.out.println(hash.get(line));

        time3 = (System.nanoTime() - start3)/1000;

        System.out.println("Query "+lineq+" "+" in "+time+" microseconds in BST, "+time2+" microseconds in Red-Black and " + time3+" microseconds in Hash Table.");

        System.out.println();
        /*Query soprano not found in 30 microseconds in BST, 12 microseconds
          in Red-Black and 2 microseconds in Hash Table*/

      }
    }
  }
}
```

I expected that for example soprano word is not in the query so code will print not found. And for example the word sunshine included in the query, prints found and the times(which I fixed).

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question here. You need to explain what behavior you expect, what behavior you get instead and also what you have done to try and reconsile the two.

Comment: How can i print the common words in query file and input file.

Comment: Show example of your inputs (not neccessarily real one, as short as possible), output you get with your code for those input strings and expected output